# Place caret in anchor of contenteditable when placed at the end of the line

Tags: javascript

I have the following contenteditable div:

```
  <div class='editable' contenteditable><a href="http://somehref" target="_blank">Place caret in here on focus</a></div>
```

I want to place the caret at the end of the text node of the anchor tag when the div has focus so that when the user edits the text they are editing the anchor's text node and not adding a new text node beside the anchor tag.

I have this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gewoluh/1/edit?html,js,console,output) that shows the problem.  If you place the cursor after the word focus and start typing, you can see that it is not updating the anchor text.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove "contenteditable" attribute from "div" and add it to "a" - then it works properly. But looks like you want it to be there, so this could be a solution. Keep in mind that you need to click inside an "a" tag for this to work.

```js
//no other javascript needed
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='editable' contenteditable>
  <a href="http://somehref"
     onmousedown="$(this).parent().removeAttr('contenteditable');"
     onblur="$(this).parent().attr('contenteditable','');"
     target="_blank"
     contenteditable>
    Place caret in here on focus
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Same result if you set the cursor after focus and type some characters, they are not within the anchor tag

Comment: That is the catch. You need to click inside `<a>` tag and move caret to the end of text or click on last character's right side so that _javascript_ that disables `contenteditable` on `<div>` fires.

Comment: I can't rely on the user to do that.  I need to somehow move the caret inside

Comment: or probably do away with the anchor tag altogether and fake it